# how to use web service on flex?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, soap

i am going to use https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/v13/AdService?wsdl .
google adwords apI to my project . so how do i use that ? do u know any example plz refer me

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question, I liked it.

Here is a tutorial which i am going to follow myself now.  It looks quite straight forward and used with Flex 3.0:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html

If you want to obtain a free serial code for Flex also for educational or out of work developers visit this link for info:

https://freeriatools.adobe.com/

Cheers,

Andrew

Comment: Thanks lot REA_ANDREW . it is very useful to me . do u know about any googleadwords API . if u know plz Explain